# Dropping multiple columns from Spark dataframe by Iterating through the columns from a Scala List of Column names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has columns around 400, I want to drop 100 columns as per my requirement.
So i have created a Scala List of 100 column names.
And then i want to iterate through a for loop to actually drop the column in each for loop iteration.

Below is the code.

```
final val dropList: List[String] = List("Col1","Col2",...."Col100”)

def drpColsfunc(inputDF: DataFrame): DataFrame = { 
    for (i <- 0 to dropList.length - 1) {
        val returnDF = inputDF.drop(dropList(i))
    }
    return returnDF
}

val test_df = drpColsfunc(input_dataframe) 

test_df.show(5)
```

Comment: I am getting a compile error that could not resolve "returnDF".
Can anyone please help to fix this.

Comment: Please make the question self-contained. Why do you put part of your question in the comments? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39786733/edit) your question with the additional information you have added in the comments !

Comment: @ Martin and Eliasah-- Done the changes in the question. Thanks

Comment: The issue that i was facing with above code is, I am getting a compile error that "could not resolve 'returnDF'". Can anyone please help to fix this.

Comment: Actually I think we cannot do this way. Reason is, dataframe itself cannot be iterated since its immutable it cannot be changed. I mean when one column is dropped the new dataframe is created in the first iteration and when in the next iteration the dataframe is still the old one.

Comment: In the new Spark Version from 2.0, I think we have API available to drop the multiple columns list using one drop statement.

Comment: I fixed this issue using the code from the source                                                                         http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Drop-multiple-columns-in-the-DataFrame-API-td25438.html

Comment: val colsToRemove = Seq("colA", "colB", "colC", etc) 
val filteredDF = df.select(df.columns 
  .filter(colName => !colsToRemove.contains(colName)) 
  .map(colName => new Column(colName)): _*)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Answer:**

```
val colsToRemove = Seq("colA", "colB", "colC", etc) 

val filteredDF = df.select(df.columns .filter(colName => !colsToRemove.contains(colName)) .map(colName => new Column(colName)): _*)
```

Comment: Works fine. Could you please elaborate significance of "_*" here ?

Comment: on `: _*` : if you know python it's similar to the unpack unary operator `*` you put in front of a list for example. The expression above before `: _*` is a sequence of `Column` (more precisely an `Array[Column]`), but (one form of) `select` expects a varargs field of `Column`, ie. a variable number of `Column` objects. See for example: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-methods-variable-arguments-varargs-fields

Comment: `df.drop(colsToRemove : _*)`  this is a simpler|cleaner solution.

Answer (score 31):

If you just want to do nothing more complex than dropping several named columns, as opposed to selecting them by a particular condition, you can simply do the following:

```
df.drop("colA", "colB", "colC")
```

Answer (score 11):

This should work fine :

```scala
val dropList : List[String]  |
val df : DataFrame  |
val test_df = df.drop(dropList : _*)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just do,

```
def dropColumns(inputDF: DataFrame, dropList: List[String]): DataFrame = 
    dropList.foldLeft(inputDF)((df, col) => df.drop(col))
```

It will return you the `DataFrame` without the columns passed in `dropList`.

As an example (of what's happening behind the scene), let me put it this way.

```
scala> val list = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
list: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> val removeThese = List(0, 2, 3)
removeThese: List[Int] = List(0, 2, 3)

scala> removeThese.foldLeft(list)((l, r) => l.filterNot(_ == r))
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

The returned list (in our case, map it to your DataFrame) is the latest filtered. After each fold, the latest is passed to the next function `(_, _) => _`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the drop operation to drop multiple columns. If you are having column names in the list that you need to drop than you can pass that using `:_*` after the column list variable and it would drop all the columns in the list that you pass.

**Scala:**

```
val df = Seq(("One","Two","Three"),("One","Two","Three"),("One","Two","Three")).toDF("Name","Name1","Name2")
val columnstoDrop = List("Name","Name1")
val df1 = df.drop(columnstoDrop:_*)
```

**Python:**
In python you can use the * operator to do the same stuff.

```
data = [("One", "Two","Three"), ("One", "Two","Three"), ("One", "Two","Three")]
columns = ["Name","Name1","Name2"]
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(columns)
columnstoDrop = ["Name","Name1"]
df1 = df.drop(*columnstoDrop)
```

Now in df1 you would get the dataframe with only one column i.e Name2.