# Drop multiple columns from spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to drop multiple columns from a dataframe. I've followed the example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818645/10836338 but it doesn't work for me. I am using spark 2.4.0

Here's what I'm doing right now. It does work, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

```
val colsToRemove = Seq("colA", "colB", "colC", etc) 

var filterdDF = df
 for(i <- 0 until colsToRemove.size){
    filterdDF = filterdDF.drop(colsToRemove(i))
}
```

Comment: `drop` also accepts a `list` of column name strings which can be used here. No need to loop.

Comment: I've already tried that but it returns an error.   

`error: overloaded method value drop with alternatives:
  (col: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (colNames: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (colName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`

Answer (score 9):

```
val filterdDF = df.drop(colsToRemove:_*)
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try this...

```
val colsToRemove = Seq("emp_id", "emp_city")

val filteredDF = ds1.select(ds1.columns.filter(colName => !colsToRemove.contains(colName)).map(colname => new Column(colname)).toList: _*)
```